# Numerical integration error

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

I am a bit puzzled by one of my textbook tasks.
I should determine the integral error $$ \int_{0}^{3} | f(t)-p_{n}(t) | d t $$
for $n=10,50,100$ using a numerical method. Where 
$$f(t) = \exp(-t)\cos(4\pi t)$$
And $p_n(t)$ is the lagrange interpolation polynomial of order max $n$.

However i can't seem to get a result that seems plausible. 
I tried the following. 
Determine 
 $f(t)-p_{n}(t)$ from the following

$$
f(x)-p(x)=\frac{1}{(n+1) !} f^{(n+1)}\left(\xi_{x}\right) \prod_{i=0}^{n}\left(x-x_{i}\right)
$$

And then integrate the right hand side.. This an error of something like $10^{10}$ when integrating using the quad method, which seems highly unlikely. Is there a simpler trick that i am missing, or where could i have gone wrong?

Comment: At the moment, you have provided no concrete details to compare/contrast with any other computation.  You might get better answers if you provide some details about your calculation, for example $\max_{0\leq t \leq 3} |f^{(11)}(t)| = 1.2{\dots} \times 10^{12}$, attained at $t = 0.049{\dots}$.

Comment: Yes, a large error is possible due to the Runge effect. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3412386/115115 for a graph of some lower-degree interpolations. Why do you not just integrate the error as it is given? There is no need to use the error formula, which usually serves to bound the error.